# Java Regex file extension

Tags: java, regex, gzip, file-extension

I have to check if a file name ends with a gzip extension. In particular I'm looking for two extensions: ".tar.gz" and ".gz". I would like to capture the file name (and path) as a group using a single regular expression excluding the gzip extension if any.
I tested the following regular expressions on this example path

```
String path = "/path/to/file.txt.tar.gz";
```

1. Expression 1:

   ```
   String rgx = "(.+)(?=([\\.tar]?\\.gz)$)";
   ```
2. Expression 2:

   ```
   String rgx = "^(.+)[\\.tar]?\\.gz$";
   ```

Extracting group 1 in this way:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rgx).matcher(path);           
if(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Both regular expressions give me the same result: `/path/to/file.txt.tar` and not `/path/to/file.txt`.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're looking for `.tar.gz` and `.gz`, aren't you just looking for `.gz`? All `.tar.gz` would be caught by an expression that catches `.gz`.

Comment: Minor comment. Your `[\\.tar]` should probably be `(\\.tar)` since `[...]` represents a character group.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following idiom to match both your path+file name, an gzip extensions in one go:

```
String[] inputs = {
        "/path/to/foo.txt.tar.gz", 
        "/path/to/bar.txt.gz",
        "/path/to/nope.txt"
 };
//                           ┌ group 1: any character reluctantly quantified
//                           |    ┌ group 2
//                           |    | ┌ optional ".tar"
//                           |    | |       ┌ compulsory ".gz"
//                           |    | |       |     ┌ end of input
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)((\\.tar)?\\.gz)$");
for (String s: inputs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: %s --> %s %n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: /path/to/foo.txt --> .tar.gz 
Found: /path/to/bar.txt --> .gz
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the part that matches the file name [reluctant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc), i.e. change `(.+)` to `(.+?)`:

```
String rgx = "^(.+?)(\\.tar)?\\.gz";
//              ^^^
```

Now you get:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rgx).matcher(path);           
if(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));   //   /path/to/file.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group based regex.

```
^(.+)/(.+)(?:\\.tar)?\\.gz$
```

And,

Get the path from index 1.

Get the filename from index 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0iM6/6)